Doubt about a proof in complex analysis
In proving that a continuous function
$$f:S(0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$$
Has a continuous extension to
$$h:\overline{B(0,1)}\to \mathbb{R}$$
Such that $h|_{B(0,1)}$ is harmonic, one needs to show that the following integral vanishes
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1-|z|^2}{|e^{i\theta}-z|^2}|f(w)-f(e^{i\theta})|d\theta$$
As $z\to w$ where $|w| = 1$. In this (pdf download) set of notes, the proof of this is given as follows:

Now, we split the integral above in two. One over the range of values of $\theta$ for which $|e^{i\theta} - w| < \delta$ and the other over the complementary range. For any $\epsilon > 0$ the former can be smaller than $\epsilon$ by the choice of $\delta$. This is because $f$ is continuous. And for fixed $\delta$ the latter tends to zero as $z$ approaches $w$ in view of property (c) of the Poisson Integral. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, the limit in Part (b) follows.

The issue with this proof is that it seems like we fix $\delta$ first, and then choose $z$ close enough to the unit circle, however, our choice of $\delta$ is such that the integral is less than $\epsilon$, but this integral necessarily depends on $z$, and so it is not possible to choose $\delta$ without first having chosen $z$, and this is not a trivial issue, since the term
$$ \frac{1-|z|^2}{|e^{i\theta}-z|^2} $$
Diverges as $z\to e^{i\theta}$. Perhaps this argument can be fixed, but I cannot see a simple way to justify it. Am I correct in finding this reasoning suspicious?
What I've tried: Some simplifying assumptions can be made. Firstly, we may assume w.l.o.g. that $w = 1$ i.e. that it lies on the positive real axis, we can make the same assumption about $z$, calling it now instead $s \in (0,1)$. If we are able to bound the integral by choosing $|s-1|<\delta$ where $\delta$ does not depend on our choice of $w$ to be on the real line, so that the same $\delta$ would work along any "ray", then through some uniform continuity arguments we get that this integral vanishes. So the new limit is taken over the real numbers, i.e. we need to show that
$$\lim_{s\to 1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1-s^2}{|e^{i\theta}-s|^2}|f(1)-f(e^{i\theta})|d\theta = 0$$

The notes are correct though maybe not clear enough; the idea is that $w$ is fixed so for fixed $\epsilon$ one finds $\delta$ st $|f(w)-f(e^{i\theta})| \le \epsilon$ for $|e^{i\theta} - w| < \delta$ (which requires continuity).
Then for all $z$ in the unit disc $$\int_{|e^{i\theta} - w| < \delta}\frac{1-|z|^2}{|e^{i\theta}-z|^2}|f(w)-f(e^{i\theta})|d\theta \le \epsilon\int_{|e^{i\theta} - w| < \delta}\frac{1-|z|^2}{|e^{i\theta}-z|^2}d\theta \le $$ $$\le \epsilon \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1-|z|^2}{|e^{i\theta}-z|^2}d\theta =2\pi \epsilon$$ since the integrand $\frac{1-|z|^2}{|e^{i\theta}-z|^2}$ is nonnegative.
And then we use that $z \to w$ so we pick $z$ close enough st $$\int_{|e^{i\theta} - w| \ge \delta}\frac{1-|z|^2}{|e^{i\theta}-z|^2}|f(w)-f(e^{i\theta})|d\theta \le \epsilon$$ since now $\delta$ is fixed and we can use property $(c)$ of the Poisson integral

Ah! Thank you, that makes it very clear, I think the crucial step that should be added for clarity is the second inequality.

yes - the nonnegativity of the Poisson kernel is crucial for all the stuff related to it
